# Convergence of $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k a_k}{n^2} \to \frac{a}{2}$ if $a_n \to a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence which converges to $a$.

> **Question** Why does 
>   $$ \frac{a_1 + 2 a_2 + \dots + n a_n}{n^2} $$
>   converge to $\frac{a}{2}$?

**Thoughts and remarks**

Since I encountered this problem in the context of Cauchy's First Limit Theorem, I thought I could use it by noting
$$
\frac{a_1 + 2 a_2 + \dots + n a_n}{n^2} = \frac{\frac{a_1}{n} + \frac{2 a_2}{n} + \dots + a_n}{n}. 
$$
This, however, is not helpful since for different $n$ the summand in the enumerator are different, so the theorem cannot be applied.

Could someone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tend to attack this sort of problem in three stages.  Can I prove the result when $a_k = a$ for all $k$?  Can I prove the result when $|a_k - a| < \varepsilon$ for all $k$ and small, positive $\varepsilon$?  Can I show that the initial segment of the sum is suppressed and the tail, which termwise approximates $a$ with error at most $\varepsilon$, dominates the result?  If you follow the same sequence of attempts, how far do you get?

Comment: Are you familiar with Cesaro-Stolz's theorem? The limit is easy to find with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, let $$b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k a_k$$
Fix $\varepsilon>0$, there is $N>0$ such that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for any integer $n\ge N$. Now, for any $n>N$ we can write $b_n$ as

$$b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k a_k +\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=N}^n k a_k $$
$$b_n-\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k a_k =\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=N}^n k a_k $$
Using the inequality $a-\varepsilon <a_n<a+\varepsilon$, we get 
$$\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=N}^n k (a-\varepsilon)<b_n-\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k a_k <\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=N}^n k (a+\varepsilon) $$

$$(a-\varepsilon)\frac{(N+n)(n-N-1)}{2n^2}<b_n-\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k a_k <(a+\varepsilon)\frac{(N+n)(n-N-1)}{2n^2} $$

Take $n\to \infty$ to get 
 $$\frac{a-\varepsilon}{2}<\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n <\frac{a+\varepsilon}{2} $$
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we get $b_n\to a/2$.

**Note:** Those details memic the proof of Stolz lemma.

Comment: Isn't there some $1/n^2$ missing in the second-last inequality?

Comment: @Diglett: Yes, I have corrected it.